# How to see several lines under one grep line

Tags: linux, grep, cat

I want to see the logs where log level is ERROR
and I want to see the stackTrace
but when I input like below
`cat app.log | grep ERROR`
I can't see the stackTrace
Is there a way to see several lines under the greped line?

Comment: read the grep man page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-A NUM` as part of the `grep` options.

For example: `cat app.log | grep ERROR -A 10` will print 10 lines after the matching line(s).

From the [grep man page](https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/grep1.html):

> -A NUM, --after-context=NUM
> Print NUM lines of trailing context after  matching  lines.
> Places a line containing a group separator (described under
> --group-separator) between contiguous  groups  of  matches.
> With  the  -o or --only-matching option, this has no effect
> and a warning is given.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -A 3 app.log
```

- `-A 3` ("after") prints matching line, and 3 more below (4 lines total)
- `-B 3` ("before") prints matching line, and 3 more before (4 lines total)
- `-C 3` ("context") prints matching line, and 3 above and 3 below (7 lines total)